# Change Device Push Notification Settings programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to change the device push notification settings programmatically. Till now I manage to take user to the setting page and he needs to enable or disable it manually . Is there any way or bunch of codes of enable push notification service?

Here is my code to take user to the push notification settings option

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:  (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

But I want to implement the push notification enable programmatically instead of taking user to the settings option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way to register for remote notifications inside the API. This is a way to ensure you do not register for Push Notification without the user consent. You cannot force the registration programatically.

[Documentation for Push Notification is available here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't enable push notification programatically. The user must be allow push notification either from the **settings** or **user prompt**